# MacBook Pro user account missing

Tags: macos, user-account, login

I changed my user account name on my MacBook Pro and as soon as I restarted my laptop my account disappeared. I tried everything online but it’s not working. I can access the guest user and another administrator account but my main account is not visible to be logged into.

What do I do??

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). Regarding your question, telling us *I tried everything online but it’s not working* doesn't actually tell as anything at all. Could you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/364827/edit) your question to clarify *what* you've tried? Otherwise we won't have the full picture, and you risk getting answers suggesting what you've already tried.

Comment: I changed my name and then shutdown the computer when I turned it back on the account wasn’t there I logged into the guest account and tried making a new account with the same name it said the account already exists. I went back to the user accounts list it appeared but I didn’t know what to do so I restarted it again to see if it comes on the log in page but it didn’t.

Comment: After that I pressed command S on the start screen and the system reboot appeared but I didn’t go through with it thinking rebooting it might lose all the information